# Passing new line characters into function javascript

Tags: javascript

I receive an array from the controller which I put into the table and generate links to "edit", "delete", and "merge". The "edit" event passes variable to function which opens dialog where variable lSynonyms should be presented as multiline similarly to Synonyms shown in the table. I tried:

```
lSynonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + '\r\n';

lSynonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + '\n';
```

Both give me error "Unterminated string constant" when I click "edit" link. If I remove \r\n the function is working good except data in textarea is not appeared as new lines. How to pass these new line correctly?

Code which generates table

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var Synonyms = '';
    var lSynonyms = '';
    for (j = 0; j < data[i]['varNames'].length; j++) {
    Synonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + '<br/>';
    lSynonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + "\r\n";
    }
$("#teamstable > tbody").append('<tr><td>' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + '</td><td>' + data[i]["stdName"] + '</td><td>' + Synonyms + '</td><td><a onclick="updateform(' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + ',\'' + data[i]["stdName"] + '\',\'' + lSynonyms + '\')">edit</a>' + '&nbsp;<a onclick="mergeform(' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + ')">merge</a>&nbsp;' + '<a onclick="RemoveTeam(' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + ')">delete</a></td></tr>');
}
```

Function to open dialog:

```
function updateform(id, rTeam, sTeam) {
    $('#id').val(id);
    $('#iID').val(id);
    $('#sTeam').val(rTeam);
    $('#vTeam').val(sTeam);
    updatedialog.dialog("open");
}
```

The dialog which is opening:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Update Dialog">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="iID">Match ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="iID" id="iID" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="rTeam">Standardized Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="sTeam" id="sTeam" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="sTeam">ID > Known Synonyms</label>
            <textarea rows="6" id="vTeam" class="form-control" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A workaround: use some other character, like `|`, then in `updateform`, do `$('#vTeam').val(sTeam.replace(/|/g, '\r\n'));`. But honestly, this is one of the problems with using inline event handlers. Look into `addEventListener` or `on()`, since you appear to be using jQuery.

Comment: That means create unique selector to every link, add `$('#a912').on("click", function(){
    $('#id').val(912);
    $('#iID').val(912);
    $('#sTeam').val("Text");
    $('#vTeam').val("Line1 \n Line2 \n");
    updatedialog.dialog("open");
});` and remove _updateform_, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have that `data` variable available, you could add `data-` attribute indicating the `i` and `j` values, allowing you to pull together the `Synonyms` or `lSynonyms` data on the fly. Same with the `stdTeamID` and `stdName` values... Let me put together an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the idea here is that the `data` variable is available in context. It might be a bit more of a hassle if you don't have it available.

But the idea is that you just need a pointer back to the data, and you can get it later. And you can put the pointer in the HTML in a `data-` property.

So here, the HTML construction is the same, except that instead of calling updateform from the HTML, you just tell it "use index 0" or whatever. I also added a `class` onto the links to make them easier to identify when attaching the event handlers.

From that piece of information, you can create the necessary arguments to `updateform` and call it.

```js
$(function() {
  function updateform(id, rTeam, sTeam) {
    /* same as before */
    console.log(id, rTeam, sTeam);
  }
  var data = [{
    stdTeamID: 912,
    stdName: "912",
    varNames: [{
        varTeamID: 913,
        varName: "913"
      },
      {
        varTeamID: 914,
        varName: "914"
      }
    ]
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var Synonyms = "";
    for (j = 0; j < data[i]['varNames'].length; j++) {
      Synonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + '<br/>';
    }
    $("#teamstable > tbody").append('<tr><td>' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + '</td><td>' + data[i]["stdName"] + '</td><td>' + Synonyms + '</td><td><a class="updateform" data-index="' + i + '"">edit</a>' + '&nbsp;<a onclick="mergeform(' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + ')">merge</a>&nbsp;' + '<a onclick="RemoveTeam(' + data[i]["stdTeamID"] + ')">delete</a></td></tr>');
  }
  $('#teamstable').on('click', '.updateform', function(e) {
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
    var teamId = data[i]["stdTeamID"];
    var teamName = data[i]["stdName"];
    var lSynonyms = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i]['varNames'].length; j++) {
      lSynonyms += data[i]['varNames'][j]['varTeamID'] + ' > ' + data[i]['varNames'][j]['varName'] + '\r\n';
    }
    updateform(teamId, teamName, lSynonyms);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="teamstable">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was incorrect in my comment about needing the `j` variable in a `data-` attribute; you actually need to create that in the event handler. You could apply the same principles to `mergeform` and `RemoveTeam` calls.

Comment: Thank you way cleaner and beautiful!

Comment: My `mergeform` function takes the only integer parameter and then opens dialog which will(or not) send ajax request to controller. `RemoveTeam` is even simpler -  directly send ajax request to the controller. Total expected rows in the table ~2600. From performance point of view and this particular events `mergeform` and `RemoveTeam` is event handler better than inline or not?

Comment: Well, if you use "delegated event handling" (as is used in the `$('#teamstable').on('click', '.updateform', function(e) {` line), the event handler is actually attached to the table, not to each anchor, so theoretically, it will have better performance, since it doesn't need ~2600 event handlers to track (well, ~5200 for the two). That said, I generally write my code first, then only fix performance when there's a measureable problem.